# What is the location for default Sharepoint Sitemap?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have the code below. I think my navigation links are stored in the sitemap. But I am not able to find sitemapfile. Can you tell me where is the location of default sitemap file?

```
<nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                                            <div id="MenuH"><div class="MenuBar ms-noList">
                                                <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaTopNavigation" BlockElement="true" CssClass="ms-displayInline ms-core-navigation" role="navigation" runat="server">
                                                    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource" Id="topNavigationDelegate">
                                                        <Template_Controls>
                                                            <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                                                                ShowStartingNode="False"
                                                                SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider"
                                                                id="topSiteMap" 
                                                                runat="server"
                                                                StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002"/>
                                                        </Template_Controls>
                                                    </SharePoint:DelegateControl>
                                                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">
                                                        <SharePoint:AspMenu
                                                            ID="TopNavigationMenu"
                                                            Runat="server"
                                                            EnableViewState="false"
                                                            DataSourceID="topSiteMap"   
                                                            AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
                                                            UseSimpleRendering="true"
                                                            UseSeparateCss="false"
                                                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                            StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                                                            AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
                                                            MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                                                            SkipLinkText="" />
                                                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                                                </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
                                            </div>
                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                              jQuery(function($) {
                                              $('#MenuH .MenuBar ul.root').BindMENU({ MenuStyle:"DefaultMenu",Orientation:"Horizontal" });
                                              });
                                            </script>
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

to get the SiteMap for the SharePoint, you have to meet the following requirement.

1. This feature is available for publishing sites only.
2. Anonymous access should be enabled for both web application and site
   collection.
3. Search should be configured in the environment.

To Enable the Site map.

1. Activate the  “Search Engine Sitemap” feature of site collection features from site settings.
2. Run the Full Search Crawl or wait for the next crawl to completed
3. The sitemap is located at the root level site collection.Now Browse to the following URL `"http://<WebApp>/sites/<SiteColl>/sitemap.xml` This file contains the location of actual sitemap and that is `http://<WebApp>/sites/<SiteColl>/sitemap0.xml.`

[Sitemaps in SharePoint 2013](https://mysharepointlearnings.wordpress.com/2013/10/20/sitemaps-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I have activated “Search Engine Sitemap”. What exactly step-2 mean?

Comment: You have to wait for the Search Service to crawl the Site collections, If it is SharePoint Online, i think you should wait for 24 hours.

Comment: It's sharepoint online. Can't I see directly where the site is hosted? I mean in IIS?

Comment: You can see only if it is on prem. SharePoint online is totally in cloud with no access to servers. so you have to wait for next crawl schedule.